# Which are the examples for contra guideline implementations/misnomers in .net/java framework?

Tags: java, .net

I can remember *Convert* class in .net which is named not in accordance with the guide lines. Any more examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, `java.lang.System.arraycopy` - note the lowercase second c.

Also `NullPointerException` in Java is better as `NullReferenceException` in .NET.

`AppDomain` violates the convention of *normally* not using abbreviations.

`Control.ID` violates the explicit convention of Pascal-casing ID to "Id" and Camel-casing it to "id".

EDIT: Due to popular demand, a couple more... although they're more just badly named than convention-defying.

`SortedList` in .NET - that explains what the *implementation* is, but doesn't give the correct impression about what the *API* is - that of a dictionary.

`Type.MakeGenericType` - it makes a *constructed* type. Ditto `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`.

Comment: +1 on the second.  When I first learned java, I was told to forget about pointers.  Then I had one of these popping up.  So, Java does have pointers after all.

Answer (score 1):

- [IPEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx) breaks the [compound word capitalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) guideline (which, oddly enough, specifically calls out endpoint as an example).
- All the Interop references are verboten, because they are an abbreviation for Interoperability. Thankfully, they left them as Interop though.

I swear there's an attribute or something that's completely misspelled, but I can't recall it off the top of my head. But, there is the always amusing case of [HTTP_REFERER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer).

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.Hashtable
```

If it's `HashSet`, and `HashMap`, then it should be `HashTable`.

Not a violation of the guidelines, but I've always hated `UndoableEdit`

My mind seems to parse that as "*Un(doable) edit*", meaning an edit that can't be done rather than the correct interpretation of "*UnDo - able Edit*", meaning an edit that can be undone.

Comment: The difference is that "Hashtable" is a closed-form compound word, whereas "Hashmap" and "Hashset" aren't. I know it's annoying though.